# InsertButton Probleme redirection to other page

Tags: reactjs, button, redux, react-bootstrap

I would like to put an Add button to my table.
I use "insertRow" in BootstrapTable, in otpions I put "insertBtn: createCustomInsertButton"
And in the createCustomInsertButton function, I have customized my button and I wish that when clicked it redirects to another page.

```
    render() {
        {
            console.log(this.props.store.environnements.length)
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <BootstrapTable selectRow={selectRow} data={this.props.store.environnements} options={options} deleteRow insertRow
                                pagination striped hover condensed>
                    <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField="id" hidden={true}>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='nom' filter={{type: 'TextFilter'}}>Nom</TableHeaderColumn>
                    <TableHeaderColumn dataFormat={buttonFormatter}>Action</TableHeaderColumn>
                </BootstrapTable>
            </div>
        );
    }

const options = {
    deleteBtn: createCustomDeleteButton,
    insertBtn: createCustomInsertButton
};

function createCustomInsertButton() {
    return (
        <InsertButton
            btnText='Ajouter'
            btnContextual='btn-success'
            className='btn-list btn-success-maif'
            btnGlyphicon='glyphicon-edit'
            onClick={test()}
       />
    );
}

function test() {
    return (
        <Redirect to='/environnement/add'></Redirect>
    );
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I'm trying to redirect from the button
Currently I tried with the function test in the "OnClick"

Comment: my error : Uncaught Invariant Violation: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 onClick = { () => test() }
```

or

```
onClick = { test }
```

If you have a SPA, you should use the Link from `react-router`

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

<Link to="/page"> Page </Link>
```

Comment: it works thank you ! i use <Link> and insert <Button>

Answer (score 1):

Provided everything above the `createCustomInsertButton` definition works the way you'd expect, `onClick` expects a function. Your code instead calls a function, so whenever `createCustomInsertButton` is invoked, `test` is too.

Instead, pass the function to `onClick` (no parentheses):

```
onClick={test}
```

From the React docs:

> With JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string.

[React Handling Events Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: I have no more mistakes using this.
However, my redirection does not work

Comment: Could you be more specific? What have you tried? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I changed the "Onclick", and I tried to click on the button, I get no error but the redirection does not work

Comment: Is `/environnement/add` supported by your router? What happens if you visit it directly (typing it straight into your browser bar and hitting enter)?

Comment: When I go to the url /environment/add my page is displayed

Comment: it works thank you ! i use <Link> and insert <Button>